# Equivalent of amssymb \square and \Diamond in Latin Modern Math?

Tags: unicode-math, latin-modern

**PROBLEM**

Using `amssymb`, I get `\square` and `\Diamond` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

BLAH $\square$ $\Diamond$ BLAH

\end{document}
```

[image: \square and \Diamond with amssymb]

How do I get the same (or very similar) symbols with Latin Modern Math?

Guided by http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf, I tried the following (using `xelatex`, of course):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

BLAH $\enclosesquare$ $\mdlgwhtlozenge$ BLAH

\end{document}
```

But both symbols are missing in the output:

[image: Missing symbols with Latin Modern Math]

The log file shows:

```
Missing character: There is no ⃞ in font LMMath-Regular/OT:script=math;language
=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ◊ in font LMMath-Regular/OT:script=math;language
=DFLT;!
```

Curiously, those log messages show the actual missing symbols!

**SOLUTION**

*Finding the math font:*

For reasons I do not completely understand, the issue of the missing Latin Modern Math font has been resolved.

While the file `latinmodern-math.otf` is indeed, as expected, in `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math`, also (via the macOS Font Book.app) I also have `lmmath-regular.otf` in `/Library/Fonts/Latin Modern`.

Whether the most recent run of the TeX Live Utility and its automatic invocation of `updmap` fixed things or not, in any case now the following loads the font as expected with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}

BLAH $\enclosesquare$ $\mdlgwhtlozenge$ BLAH

\end{document}
```

*Getting the two symbols I wanted:*

The preceding source also now prints the characters `\enclosesquare` and `\mdlgwhtlozenge` in the pdf.

However, I had been trying those two as substitutes for what I *really* wanted (before I descended into the rabbit hole of the missing font file), namely, by using one of the usual work-arounds: loading `amsfonts` before `unicode-math`. So now this does what I really was after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for \square & \Diamond
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}

HELLO $\square$ $\diamond$ GOODBYE

\end{document}
```

[image: \square and \Diamond substituted]

Comment: works ok here. Is your system up-to-date? Did you try with lualatex?

Comment: My system (TeXLive 2019 under macOS, all packages updated today) is utterly up-to-date. With lualatex, same result of vanished symbols in the pdf and same error messages in the log.

Comment: then show the log-file of lualatex.

Comment: I can’t reproduce your bug on my TeX Live 2019. Latin Modern Math v  1.959 contains both symbols. It’s possible you have an older version of the font on your system; what does `luaotfload-tool --find "Latin Modern Math"` tell you? What version of the font do you have installed, according to `otfinfo -i`? Does it work if you load `latinmodern-math.otf`?

Comment: *In general*, the fix for missing symbols is to load them from a different math font with `range=`, e.g. `\setmathfont[range={\enclosesquare, \mdlgwhtlozenge}, Scale=MatchUppercase]{STIX Two Math}`. But you should not need to here.

Comment: Your system doesn't find the math font but a local version of lmroman: /Library/Fonts/Latin Modern/lmroman10-regular.otf. Try to call the math font by file name instead of the font name.

Comment: `/Library/Fonts/Latin Modern/lmroman10-regular.otf` is the text font; the corresponding math font is `/Library/Fonts/Latin Modern/lmmath-regular.otf`. But If I replace `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}` by `\setmathfont{lmmath-regular.otf}` or `\setmathfont{lmmath-regular}`, gives respective errors `fontspec Error: The font "lmmath-regular" cannot be found.` and from `kpathsea: Running mktexmf 'OT'` error `I dan't find file 'OT'`....

Comment: ... Moreover, if I disable that .otf font (using  Font Book) and revert to using the full name `Latin Modern Math`, then from `kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid finename 'Latin Modern Math/OT', contains ' ' ` followed by `fontspace Error: The font Latin Modern Math cannot be found`. I did check, and the requisite file is there: `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm-math/latinmodern-math.otf`.

Comment: You should use @UlrikeFischer if you want me to get notified by a comment. Beside this: if the filename is `latinmodern-math.otf` then why on earth didn't you try to load it with this name?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I tried loading the file by name `Latin Modern Math` (a) by analogy with successfully using, e.g., name `TeX Gyre Termes Math` (despite file name `texgyretermes-math.otf`); and (b) from various SE posts doing the same, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234305/alleged-missing-characters-in-latin-modern-math, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417928/latin-modern-math-doesnt-have-boldface.